# Iterating through two lists with different lengths

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through two lists with different lengths and compare the strings inside them, but I keep getting this TypeError "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Here's my code. How can I go about this?

[image]

Comment: please, do not upload a picture of your code, upload the code itself.

Comment: You’re creating two sets from your two lists and then converting the sets back to lists. And `i` and `j` are elements of your lists (i.e. strings) which you can’t use to index a set. And your `print()` is empty so it won’t show you anything useful either. And your second list seems to miss `"` to open and close the strings around the second and third element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above, there are a bunch of problems with your code. To get you started, though, please look at this working example and understand what’s happening:

```
color_list_1 = ["White", "Black", "Red"]
color_list_2 = ["Red", "Green", "Brown"]

for color_1, color_2 in zip(color_list_1, color_list_2):
    if color_1 == color_2:
        print("Equal:", color_1, color_2)
```

Play around with it, make the lists different lengths and explore.

Comment: Ah okay I see now! I did not need an extra variable for indexes. I was thinking of how to iterate through two lists at the same time so I used the zip() but did not know if I still needed to iterate the list[index]. The exercise stars with the sets so that’s why I first converted them into lists since sets are unordered. But thank you! This makes a lot of sense

Comment: Think of lists and sets as a “collection” of data (one ordered, one unordered) and Python’s `for … in …` is a way to [iterate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) over the elements of a collection. The implementation of the collection ensures that you access every element.